# Why do I get an error when I try to click outside the inventory / in the inventory where there's no item

Tags: java, bukkit

I am using Spigot 1.14 and when I try to click in the inventory or outside the inventory where there is no item I get an error.

I have tried with different methods such as:

```
e.getCurrentItem().getItemMeta().getDisplayName()
e.getCurrentItem().getItemMeta().hasDisplayName()
```

and some other methods but none of them seem to work.

```
if (e.getCurrentItem().getItemMeta().getDisplayName() != null && (e.getCurrentItem().getItemMeta().getDisplayName().equalsIgnoreCase("§eMystery Box"))) {
```

When I click outside the inventory or in the inventory where there is no item I get this error message: https://pastebin.com/v0wDB2gp

Saying that it could not pass the inventory click event.

Comment: You need to post your full `clickevent` class, or if it's too big then only post the problematic method, around line 23

Comment: The if statement above is line 23

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code and the stacktrace everything I can say is that either `e.getCurrentItem().getItemMeta()` or `e.getCurrentItem()` is returning `null`.

**Stacktrace**

```
Could not pass event InventoryClickEvent to MysteryBox v1.0-SNAPSHOT
org.bukkit.event.EventException: null
        ...
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.chefren.mysterybox.clickevent.onclick(clickevent.java:23) ~[?:?]
        ...
```

**See also**
[What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors)
[What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)